# Solid volume using double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

I'm trying to calculate the volume of solid bounded by
$$z=3\arctan(\frac{y}{x}), z=0, \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$$
using double integrals, but I dont know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume V can be found in the integral
$$\iint_\omega 3 \tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{y}{x}\bigg )dydx$$

Where $\omega$ is the area bounded by $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 2 \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$

Let $u = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $u$ is between $0$ and $\pi$

$v = \frac{y}{x}$ and $v$ is between $0$ and $\infty$.

Then J :
$$J = \bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\bigg ) - \bigg (\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\bigg ) \bigg(\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\bigg)$$

$$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + v^2}}\frac{u}{(1 + v^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} - \frac{-uv}{(1 + v^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{v}{\sqrt{1 + v^2}}$$
$$= \frac{u}{1 + v^2}$$

$$V = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\tan^{-1}v} 3\tan^{-1}v \frac{u}{1 + v^2} dudv$$

$$= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{3}{2} 4(\tan^{-1}v)^{3} \frac{dv}{1 + v^2}$$

Let $v = \tan t$ and $dv = \sec^2 t dt$

$$V = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 6t^3 dt = \frac{3\pi^4}{32}$$

I have a book with the same question but more general.  It asks to find the volume for 
$$z = c tan^{-1} (\frac{y}{x})$$
And
$$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = a tan^{-1} (\frac{y}{x})$$

And the answer is
$$\frac{\pi^4a^2c}{128}$$
[image: Question No 4033 in my book[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bWbd.png)

Comment: According to the book, the correct anwser is $2pi/3$

Comment: I cannot attach the answer for the question in my book.  I have to add it in the second answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This the answer for question No 4033 in my book.